# While using axios I got 521 response code in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to do a request to this URL, and getting an error

```
axios.get('http://8btc.com/member.php?mod=logging&action=login')
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err.response.status))
```

Output is 521

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code 521 means that the server is down. This is not official standard error code, but used by some systems.

http://getstatuscode.com/521

Basically a web server can return you any error code at any time. It all depends how it is programmed to work. So your best bet is to work together with the admins of 8btc to understand why you are getting that response back.

For some extra information you can try to see if the error message received from the server tells you more details. See the error handling documentation: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#handling-errors

Based on this documentation you should check what information you have in `err.response.data`and `err.response.headers`

Comment: The URL works on my browser yes. Try to get the error description printed out (see my edit in the answer). They might have some rules in place to block certain requests. Ultimately the people maintaining the server application can tell you why you are getting that response from them

Comment: err.response.headers looks like this

Comment: { date: 'Thu, 17 Aug 2017 15:45:45 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/html',
  connection: 'close',
  'set-cookie': [ 'yd_cookie=572261fd-80db-495201074e5cf52a0601ac1a2bcc1dcb3229; Expires=1502991945; Path=/; HttpOnly' ],
  'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
  'content-length': '1870',
  server: 'WAF/2.4-12.1' }